# Помогите чуть допилить скрипт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Скрипт, чтоб при открытии одного попапа, другой попап закрывался (если он на тот момент открыт). Спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/52hxLrsk/10/

```
var items = $('.btn-win');
      for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
          $(items[i]).click(function () {
          var id = $(this).attr('href');
              $(id).toggleClass("active");
              return false;
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn-win').click(function() {
  $('.btn-win').not(this).each(function() {
    $($(this).attr("href")).removeClass("active");
  });
  $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.win {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.win.active {
  display: block;
}

.win:nth-child(1) {
  background: pink;
  /*top: 100px;*/
}

.win:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  /*top: 200px;*/
}

.win:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
  /*top: 300px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#win1" class="btn-win">Окно 1</a>
<a href="#win2" class="btn-win">Окно 2</a>
<a href="#win3" class="btn-win">Окно 3</a>
<div>
  <div class="win" id="win1">Окно 1</div>
  <div class="win" id="win2">Окно 2</div>
  <div class="win" id="win3">Окно 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/52hxLrsk/45/ не работает. Походу вы не тестили ваш вариант

Comment: @websterjoy я никогда не тестирую